# How to connect FastAPI with ClickHouse database using DSN?

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, clickhouse

I am trying to connect my FastAPI application with a ClickHouse database. I want to establish the connection using a Data Source Name (DSN). I am using the `clickhouse-driver` package and would like to configure the connection parameters in the DSN format.

Here is what I have done so far:

- Installed the necessary packages (`fastapi` and `clickhouse-driver`).
- Created a FastAPI application.
- Initialized a ClickHouse client.

However, I am unsure how to configure the connection using a DSN. I would like to provide the username, password, host, port, and database in the DSN string.

Could someone please guide me on how to set up the connection between FastAPI and ClickHouse using a DSN? Any help or example code would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my current code snippet:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from clickhouse_driver import Client

app = FastAPI()

dsn = "clickhouse://username:password@host:port/database"
client = Client(dsn=dsn)

@app.get("/your-endpoint")
async def get_data_from_clickhouse():
    query = "SELECT * FROM your_table"
    result = client.execute(query)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!